# Why is overloading not implemented at runtime?

Tags: java, runtime, overloading

Why is overloading generally not implemented at runtime?
What are the difficulties/implications in allowing a language to select overloaded implementations at runtime, based on the actual (not declared) parameter type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Overloading must be resolved at compile time as it might be ambiguous to resolve the method dispatch at runtime.**

Imagine the following snippet (valid and compilable Java program):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object object = new Clazz();

        method(object);
    }

    static class Clazz implements Interface1, Interface2 {}

    interface Interface1 {}

    interface Interface2 {}

    private static void method(Object o)     {}
    private static void method(Interface1 i) {}
    private static void method(Interface2 i) {}
}
```

If overloading will really be resolved at runtime, it will be ambigous which method to call as `Clazz` implements both interfaces.

Comment: Maybe in dynamic language which Java is not.